# issue in preventing user from entering empty string in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery ajax post and when a user inputs some text and presses enter in a textbox this ajax will trigger and show the value of text box in a `<pre>` html element. http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2133/ obviuosly this jsfiddle does not show anything because I haven't put the ajax post inside it. But when the user writes nothing and presses enter this ajax is triggered and returns something. But how can I catch the empty strings from user?

This is located in my view:

```
 if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                var currentLine = $('#terminal').text();
                var inputData = $(e.currentTarget).val();

                $('#terminal').text(currentLine + "\r\n" + inputData + "\r\n"); //show the current and previous value
                $("#textInput").val(" $> ");
                AjaxPost(inputData);

            }
```

and this ajax post is in model:

```
 AjaxPost : function(dataAttribute, view, cacheId) {

        console.log(cacheId);
         var that = this;

         if(dataAttribute === ""){
            view.showMessage( " " , true);
         }

          $.ajax({

           type : "POST",
           url : "/api/user" , 
           datatype : "application/json",
           contentType: " text/plain",
           data : dataAttribute,
           success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);

           },
           error : function(error) {


           },
```

My problem is that my input data has default value of `"$>"` so I cannot check this condition if `(inputdata === "" )` because it is always full! Have any ideas?

Comment: how about (inputdata === "$>" ) ?

Comment: Tried inputdata.length > 2 or inputdata != "$>"

Comment: as metaphy mentioned, so you could have these two conditions: if(dataAttribute === "" || dataAttribute === "$>")

Comment: @ metaphy : it is always (inputdata === "$>" ) so still after entering with empty string the ajax post returns sth

Comment: @user2766267: try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

if the input value defaults to `"$>"` then you only need to check that too, and return to avoid the ajax call:

`if(dataAttribute === "" || dataAttribute === "$>") {
    view.showMessage( " " , true);
    return;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = inputdata.match(/\s*\$\>\s*/)
if (inputdata === m[0]){
    console.log('empty')
}
else{
    console.log('not empty')
}
```